# Connecting the reception for the emails to a java application

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta, mail-server

I created a mail server with Postfix and courier , and I create automatically virtual emails address for many clients , so I work with a mysql database to store these virtual emails to connect them to postfix . What I will do is sending emails to external address with java mail , I didn't try it yet . (I'm not sure about this choice , if you have another suggestion please tell me).

And my problem now , is how I can rely the receiving emails (content,sender..) to a java program to display for example the message/content of the email to every client . Any ideas please ?

Comment: Arrange for something like Procmail to feed the incoming messages to your program.

Comment: Ok tripleee , thank's a lot , I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the procmail suggestion above, you can have the messages delivered to a mailbox and have your JavaMail problem poll the mailbox for newly arrived messages.  The IMAP IDLE command can make the polling relatively quick and efficient, but it does require a connection to the mail server held open.

Comment: This IMAP IDLE seems really interesting; going to take a look at it, hopefully I'll have a better understanding of how this works